# Couldn't connect to sql server database from ado.net

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I wrote simple sql script that creates my database:

```
create database [MaterialStream];
exec sp_addlogin N'MaterialStreamLogin', N'123', N'MaterialStream'
exec sp_adduser N'MaterialStreamLogin', N'MaterialStreamUser', N'db_owner'
```

And then couldn't connect to my database from ADO.NET. How can I set up credentials for my user?

Comment: Also I granted access to my database:

grant all to [MaterialStreamUser];

Comment: What is the exception/error that you get when you try to connect using ADO.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried logging on as that user using Management Studio?  It's possible it's defaulted to requesting a password change on first login or similar.

Comment: No, it's not defaulted to equesting a password change on first login

Comment: I would suggest trying to connect using Management Studio.  It may be that remote connections aren't enabled or something like that.  Management Studio from your dev box (I assume that's where the ADO.Net is) will give an idea of what's going on.